# Set custom numbering in a nested Table of contents in MS Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word

In a Word document I have a nested document which has a Table of contents. That Table is generated automatically. The Table considers pages of whole document while I neeed it to consider only pages of the nested document. In other words, my nested Table of contents starts from the page 40 while it has to start from page 1. How to do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is the document nested?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Table of Contents for only a part of a document by using the \b switch to look at only text within a bookmarked area. It will, however, use the page numbers that Word has applied, it will not start from the beginning of the bookmark. If you need help with this switch in the TOC field, I would be happy to provide that.

By starting your nested document in a new Word section, you can restart the page numbering there if you want. This is done in the Format Page Numbers dialog. Again, it requires a section break.